# Capturing the message that killed an actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm trying to respond to the sender of message when the receiving actor dies due to that message. If I `Restart` the actor on failure I get

```
preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any])
```

but now I'm committed to restarting.

If I `Stop` the actor, i only get

```
postStop()
```

with no knowledge what stopped myself.

Meanwhile in the supervisor, I only get the `Throwable` and no indication of what caused it.

I suppose, I can dig through the `DeadLetters` post actor termination, but that seems like a noisy approach, since I'd have to listen to all of dead letters and somewhere correlate the termination with the deadletter event stream.

**UPDATE:** `DeadLetter` really doesn't seem to be an option. The message that caused the death doesn't even go to DeadLetters, it just disappears.

Is there a mechanism I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/jBXJElWhyFU) on the Akka Users List, there isn't a mechanism in the actor supervision death cycle to accomplish this. Moreover, the documentation explicitly states that the message is dropped:

> [**What happens to the Message**](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/actors.html#What_happens_to_the_Message)
>
> If an exception is thrown while a message is being processed (i.e. taken out of its mailbox and handed over to the current behavior), then this message will be lost. It is important to understand that it is not put back on the mailbox. So if you want to retry processing of a message, you need to deal with it yourself by catching the exception and retry your flow.

The ideal solution would be to use a dedicated actor for *dangerous* operations and have the initiator monitor the death of that actor to determine failure.

As my scenario arose from something considered *safe* but that had a bug in it, the separate actor option would have been *after the fact*. To avoid wrapping all code paths in `try/catch` but be able to guard more complicated and critical flows, I ended up with creating a wrapper for `receive` that let's me intercept exceptions:

```
object SafeReceive {
  def apply(receive: Receive)(recover: Any => PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit]): Receive =
    new Receive {
      override def isDefinedAt(x: Any): Boolean = receive.isDefinedAt(x)

      override def apply(v1: Any): Unit = try {
        receive(v1)
      } catch recover(v1)
    }
}
```

which I can use for select actors like this:

```
def receive = SafeReceive {
  case ... => ...
} {
  msg => {
    case e: Exception =>
      sender ! OperationFailed(msg, e)
      throw e
  }
}
```